# Unable to de-serialize a json object at controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Json

```
var jdondata=  [
        {
            "address": "address1",
            "email": "a@ab.com",
            "name": "sharad",
            "phone": "222222222"
        },
        {
            "address": "address2",
            "email": "b@gamil.com",
            "name": "hemant",
            "phone": "344324554"
        },
        {
            "address": "address2",
            "email": "c@ss.com",
            "name": "Madhur",
            "phone": "222222"
        }
    ]
```

and respective class

```
  public class addresslists
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
```

And I am passing data from jquery like

```
 var url = "/ContactGrabber/SaveImportedContacts";
    var postData = { "listGmail": data, "service": "gmail" };
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: postData ,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback(response);
                    }
                    // openNewWindow(response);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('error = ' + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

and my controller method is

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveImportedContacts(List<addresslists> listGmail, string service)
{
     return null;
}
```

Now in listGmail parameter I am getting three elements of array but all have null values. service variable is getting populated correctly.

Please help me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Properties not Fields:

```
public class addresslists
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

There are a multitude of problems.  First you should always `stringify()` your objects because jQuery may not pass Javascript Objects as Forms back properly.  When doing so it is required to set the contentType:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: JSON.stringify(postData),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (response) {
    console.log('success');         
    console.log(response);          
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.log('error');           
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  } 
});
```

I'd always recommend wrapping your response into a ViewModel:

```
public class SaveContactsViewModel
{
  public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
  public string Service { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Then your controller method should look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveImportedContacts(SaveContactsViewModel model)
{
  return null;
}
```

I've spent some time wrapping [this up in a DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rQo5gX) with the results in the console.log (developer tools log).  I have to leave but I'll get back to this in 3-4 hours.

Comment: I made my class as you suggested but unable to get the data.

Comment: I'll update this more later.

Comment: This works in visual studio, but not on dotnetfiddle.net.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Your Json Classes Should Look like this :-

```
    public class Address
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Json Arrays can automatically be model binded to List, Arrays, IEnumerable, ICollection, IList.

Comment: Yeh, rename `Addresses` -> `Address`, remove `Addressdata` as not needed, and show `public JsonResult SaveImportedContacts(List<Address> listGmail, string service)` and it'd be perfect

Comment: Updated as requested.

Comment: I made my class as you suggested but unable to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use array instead of List<>

```
public JsonResult SaveImportedContacts(addresslists[] listGmail, string service)
```